# pgfplots with gnuplot and raw input for embedded data

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

I would like to have the following gnuplot graph (that's just an exemple), which is using **embedded data** instead of an external file:

```
$data << EOD
1 5
2 10
3 1
EOD ;
plot $data using ($1):($2) with lines;
```

I tried the following simple approach, which obviously is not working as intended: the generated gnuplot code is missing the line breaks, which are necessary for a correct processing by gnuplot:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot]{
    $data << EOD
     1 5
     2 10
     3 1
EOD ;
    plot $data using ($1):($2) with lines;
   };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is it possible to feed gnuplot raw input (preserving line break) to `\addplot` ?